# When notifications is opened it displays content of the previous notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I have an app in Android that displays the latest news. When there a big story or breaking news I send a notification to the app using GCM. But I have a problem. The scenario of this problem is like this:

- I send notifications for the first news
- The user doesn't want to open it so he swipes it off
- After a while a send another notifications for another news, different from the first one
- When the user opens it, it display the first news, not the second one, the right one.

The code that I used is like below:

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    public static final int notifyID = 9001;
    JSONArray array_add = null;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    // object helper to store the notification configuration
    private SharedPreferenceNotification shared_pref;

    String type, content, nr, title, link, subtype;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("[" + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY)
                        + "]");
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {


        try {
            array_add = new JSONArray(msg);

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < array_add.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = array_add.getJSONObject(i);
                    type = c.getString(Utils.NOT_TYPE);

                    content = "[" + c.getString(Utils.NOT_CONTENT) + "]";

                    JSONArray content_a = new JSONArray(content);
                    for (int j = 0; j < content_a.length(); j++) {

                        JSONObject b = content_a.getJSONObject(j);
                        title = b.getString(Utils.NOT_TITLE);
                        nr = b.getString(Utils.NOT_NR);
                        link = b.getString(Utils.NOT_LINK);
                        subtype = b.getString(Utils.NOT_SUBTYPE);
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        Tracker t = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this)
                .newTracker("UA-2983962-14");

        // Build and send an Event.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .setCategory("Notifications")
                .setAction(type)
                .setLabel("Dergimi")
                .build());


        // initialize shared preference manager
        shared_pref = new SharedPreferenceNotification(this);

        if (shared_pref.getValue(type)) {
            Intent resultIntent;
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = null;




            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("news"){

                resultIntent =new Intent(this, ViewInWeb.class);
                Bundle basket = new Bundle();
                basket.putString(TimeUtils.TAG_LINK,link );
                basket.putString(TimeUtils.TAG_TITLE,title );
                basket.putInt("TYPE", 1);
                resultIntent.putExtras(basket);

                t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                        .setCategory("Notifications")
                        .setAction(type)
                        .setLabel(title)
                        .build());

                resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                displayNot(resultPendingIntent);

                Log.e("Erdhi ketu", "Erdhi ketuttttttt");
            }


        }
    }

    private void displayNot(PendingIntent resultPendingIntent){

        MyApplication mApplication = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();

        mApplication.getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("AppName").setContentText(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // Set pending intent
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
        int defaults = 0;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        // Set the content for Notification
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(title);
        // Set autocancel
        mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // Post a notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(nr),
                mNotifyBuilder.build());


    }
```

Any idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: set  Pending Intent  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: Yes , it works, but if the user has not opened a notification yet, so there are two notifications, the first one takes the content of the second

Comment: if user does not open notification and 2 notification come then previous notification is updated or you can say overwrite by this..

Comment: If you only want to have one `Notification` at any given time, you need to make sure that `nr` always has the same value. In that case, when you post a new `Notification` it will overwrite the older one.

Answer (score 0):

From your description you may want to consider using [GCM Notification Messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support).

Notification messages are automatically handled by the Android system. You can also set a **tag** field that will cause current notifications and their associated data to be replaced by newly sent notifications and data.

You can also specify a click_action which will determine where in your app the user is taken on tapping the notification.